# Concatenate (paste) elements based on indices

Tags: r

I want to concatenate (`paste`) rows of an elements in a data.frame based on indices.  How can I do this efficiently?  This is easy with a unique identifier but here I have indices not a factor to concatenate on.  All package and base solution options welcomed.

```
indexes <- list(
    2:3,
    6:8,
    11:12
)


dat <- data.frame(
    x = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 2, 2, 1),
    y = LETTERS[1:13],
    z = "PP", stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

   x y  z
1  1 A PP
2  2 B PP
3  2 C PP
4  3 D PP
5  4 E PP
6  5 F PP
7  5 G PP
8  5 H PP
9  6 I PP
10 7 J PP
11 2 K PP
12 2 L PP
13 1 M PP
```

Desired output:

```
   x y         z
1  1 A        PP
2  2 B, C     PP
3  3 D        PP
4  4 E        PP
5  5 F, G, H  PP
6  6 I        PP
7  7 J        PP
8  2 K, L     PP
9  1 M        PP
```

Comment: Is it just by chance that your aggregation grouping corresponds to `data.table::rleid(dat$x)`? Something along the lines of `dat[, list(y =toString(y), z = z[1L]), list(x=rleid(x))]` might work if it's not such by chance

Comment: Yeah I was just going to ask the same thing, why `x` corresponds to `indexes`?

Comment: @docendodiscimus Yes by chance.  indixes may also be `indexes <- list(
    2:3,
    6:8
)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another `base R` method:

```
indx <- !(1:nrow(dat) %in% unlist(lapply(indexes, '[', -1)))
transform(dat, y=ave(y, cumsum(indx), FUN=toString))[indx,]
#    x       y  z
# 1  1       A PP
# 2  2    B, C PP
# 4  3       D PP
# 5  4       E PP
# 6  5 F, G, H PP
# 9  6       I PP
# 10 7       J PP
# 11 2    K, L PP
# 13 1       M PP
```

---

**Explanation**

Some insight into how `!(1:nrow(dat) %in% unlist(lapply(indexes, '[', -1)))` came about:

I tried to find an index to group by. I started from the end and worked backwards. I knew that if I could get:

```
1 2 2 3 4 5 5 5 6 7 8 8 9
```

I could use `ave` and run `toString`. I thought what true and false combination would be needed to make `cumsum` give the above index as output. I wrote that out:

```
cumsum(c(T, T, F, T, T, T, F, F, T, T, T, F, T))
 [1] 1 2 2 3 4 5 5 5 6 7 8 8 9
```

I needed to find a way to create that logical index. If all of the `indexes` list elements that aren't the first were false, I'd have the logical index I needed.

```
unlist(lapply(indexes, '[', -1))
[1]  3  7  8 12
```

You'll notice that those positions are all of the false values in the index.

**dplyr**

I guess it's only fair to add dplyr to the mix:

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(indx = na.omit(c(T, x != lead(x)))) %>% 
  group_by(ind2=cumsum(indx)) %>% 
  mutate(y=toString(y)) %>%
  filter(indx)
```

Comment: Thank you @DavidArenburg. It's that dubstep playlist working :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's one possible solution in base R:

```
dat[sapply(indexes, "[", 1), "y"] <- sapply(indexes, function(i)  {
    paste(dat[["y"]][i], collapse = ", ")
})

dat[  setdiff(  1:nrow(dat), 
                        setdiff(
                          unlist(indexes),
                          sapply(indexes, "[", 1)
                          )
                        ), ]

   x       y  z
1  1       A PP
2  2    B, C PP
4  3       D PP
5  4       E PP
6  5 F, G, H PP
9  6       I PP
10 7       J PP
11 2    K, L PP
13 1       M PP
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible `data.table` solution using `set`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
for(i in seq_along(indexes)) {
  set(dat, i = indexes[[i]], j = 2L, value = dat[indexes[[i]], toString(y)])
}
unique(dat, by = "y")
#    x       y  z
# 1: 1       A PP
# 2: 2    B, C PP
# 3: 3       D PP
# 4: 4       E PP
# 5: 5 F, G, H PP
# 6: 6       I PP
# 7: 7       J PP
# 8: 2    K, L PP
# 9: 1       M PP
```

The idea here is to only operate on the indexes specified in `indexes` while modifying only the `y` column. It's not vary clear to me how this should result if `z` and `x` vary per these indices, which leaves you the option to set the variables in the `by` argument of the `unique` method of `data.table`